# Анимация фрагментов

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

начал работать с фрагментами, и возник такой вопрос: Есть ли в Android студии возможность анимировать переход между фрагментами, как Viewpager, но с другой анимацией (например, отображение фрагментов, как вкладки у сафари браузера), и где про это можно почитать? Или придется писать свои?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да можно. Единственное, что версия андроид нужно будет отслеживать, так как не все поддерживают анимацию. Простой вариант - создание xml с transitions анимацией. 
https://medium.com/bynder-tech/how-to-use-material-transitions-in-fragment-transactions-5a62b9d0b26b

Answer (score 1):

По сути, можно делать все, что хотите. Как вариант, можете поискать на GitHub уже готовые библиотеки, с функционалом, который вам нужен, т.е. переход фрагментов, а также их анимация. К примеру - https://github.com/kakajika/FragmentAnimations . Также можно сделать анимацию замещения 1го фрагмента на 2ой в FrameLayout. Стоит просто добавить одну строку кода - `ft?.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,android.R.anim.slide_out_right)`